# HP ProLiant DL380 G6 GPU installation

Tags: hardware, hp-proliant, pci-express, graphics-processing-unit

I have a Proliant DL380 G6 and I want to build a Graphics card into it. To be specific, it is a GTX 960 from Asus. The card When I now want to build it in, I am pretty shure I need a pcie slot riser, which one would you recommend? And also, can I just plug the card in on the SAS Connector A or B on the motherboard? If no, how would I get power to the card? I post a picture of my server below.[the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq3OU.jpg)

Comment: This GPU will not fit in this server. It is more than 2 slots wide.

Answer (score 3):

Your server is missing the entire PCIe riser assembly. It occupies the area outlined in pink below. You didn't notice that the rear part of the server is missing?

[image]

In order to use this system with PCIe cards, including your graphics card, you need the system's plastic air baffle (496061-001) and the entire DL380 G6 PCIe cage (496060-001).

Air baffle.
[image]

This is the PCIe riser cage which holds modular PCIe riser boards.
[image]

[image]

The cage takes one or two PCIe riser cards.
[image]

Risers can supply auxiliary power for some GPUs ([see this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X109A.jpg)), but it looks like your server is incomplete and missing other critical components.

---

Edit:

Here are the HP PCIe riser options from DL380 G6 [quickspecs](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/gethtml.aspx?docname=c04282582):

[image]

Comment: I have the Air baffle and the PCIe riser cage they were next to it ,but I dont have a PCIe riser card, which one would you use (do you know a product nacme)? And also, Is there a way to get extra power to the gpu ?

Comment: Where did you obtain this server? The face that your PCIe risers are missing is not normal. See the update at the bottom of my answer for part numbers.

Comment: I got this server used from a company for free so I  dont complaing ^^. But I can buy the extender card for like 6€. But do you think, with 2x460 Watt psu's I have enough power to take the gtx680 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the x16 Riser card.
The cheapest I can find them being sold for is $105 with the average price being $185 (USD).
Good luck finding them for 6 euros. You can't use the 3 Slot riser that is sold ever where cheap since that is only x8. 
These servers sell for only ~$140 on average for the whole system on eBay which is less $ than just the x16 riser card. Sadly they rarely include a x16 riser as they seem to be rare.
As for the power, both of mine include 2 750 watt PSU so that is strange that yours only have 460 watt PSUs. The 2nd PSU is only for Redundancy to kick in if 1 of them stops working as to prevent power loss & server downtime. They also don't have a bunch of connectors coming out from them to plug into your GPU. You may need to use an extra ATX power supply that you just turn on by connecting the green pin to black on the 24pin mobo cable and use the PCI-E power from it to power the GPU.